# Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

My Code:

```
   <div class="btn-group" *ngFor="let table of tables; index as i">
     <label [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="btn btn-info" [(ngModel)]="checkModel[i]" [ngClass]="checkModel[i] ? 'set' : 'reset'"
                   btnCheckbox tabindex="0" btnRadio="middle" role="button">{{table.number}}</label>
   </div>
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

---

**Solution:** Removing `btnRadio="middle"`

Comment: My guess, not knowing what these directives are and where they come from, is that the error comes from the usage of both btnRadio and btnCheckbox.

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero. That was the causing the error!